# Detection of peaks in the frequency spectrum without using FFTs MATLAB

Tags: matlab, frequency-analysis

Assuming I have a signal x(t), would it be possible for me to detect the peak in the frequency spectrum (that is, the frequency with the highest energy content) without using FFTs ?

*PS - I saw something in Wavelet Decomposition called scale2freq(). I looked over that in the MATLAB help page and it ended up confusing me. Does the function have anything to do with frequency representations? If yes, how do I find peak frequencies using it?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is called a **pitch detection algorithm** and there is a variety of them in time-domain or frequency-domain (or both of them). Please search google for "pitch detection algorithms" for further reference or check selected links for a quick overview:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm
- http://sound.eti.pg.gda.pl/student/eim/synteza/leszczyna/index_ang.htm

In time-domain some simple approach is to locate peaks of autocorrelation function. Indeed autocorrelation is maximal at t=0 and then next peaks gives an estimation of the main period:

```
ncount = 10000;
Ts = 0.0001; % Sampling period
t = (1:ncount) * Ts; % Sampling times
f = sin(2*pi*60*t) + 0.1*sin(2*pi*200*t) + 0.01 * randn(1, length(t)); % Signal

R = xcorr(f);
[~, locs] = findpeaks(R);
meanLag = Ts * mean(diff(locs));       
pitch = 1 / meanLag; ===> Will be around 60 Hz
```

This approach is ok for very basic signals, you'll probably have to refine it upon you situation (noise level, periodicity, multi-tone, etc...). See above references for more refined algorithms.